# Send a message to new Websocket connection in AWS API Gateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway websocket endpoint for $connect which calls a lambda function.  I want that lambda function to send back a message to the user after they connect.  Is there any way to do this?

This is what I have tried in the lambda.  The message I send is never received, and I assume that is because the connection is not completed yet.  However I don't see any way I can send a message after it has been connected.

```
import {
  ApiGatewayManagementApiClient,
  PostToConnectionCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi";

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const domain = event.requestContext.domainName;
  const stage = event.requestContext.stage;
  const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
  const callbackUrl = `https://${domain}/${stage}`;
  const client = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({ endpoint: callbackUrl });

  const requestParams = {
    ConnectionId: connectionId,
    Data: JSON.stringify({ data: "Hello World" }),
  };

  const command = new PostToConnectionCommand(requestParams);

  try {
    await client.send(command);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200
  };
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Your code seems correct as per AWS Documentation. In order to send message to a socket you need to establish the connect first. Without that you cannot send message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this inside of the handler because the connection is only established once the handler returns without an error.

> Until execution of the integration associated with the $connect route is completed, the upgrade request is pending and the actual connection will not be established. If the $connect request fails (e.g., due to AuthN/AuthZ failure or an integration failure), the connection will not be made.

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-route-keys-connect-disconnect.html)

You could use another AWS service such as SQS in order to add a message to the queue and have that trigger a lambda which would send the message

Comment: Is there anyway to send Connection-ID or some message back to client onConnect with aws websocket without using SQS